# Using the result of Type.getClassFields()

Tags: haxe

How can I make use of the *static* field names returned by [`getClassFields()`](http://api.haxe.org/Type.html#getClassFields)?

`Type` itself doesn't seem to have any functions related to this, and if you use `Reflect` like this on a field name returned by the above:

```
trace(Reflect.field(Type.createEmptyInstance(Type.resolveClass(...)), fieldName));
```

...you get:

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

My goal is to obtain the *value* of a static field using a classname given dynamically, e.g. how can I get `"hi"` out of:

```
class Blah {
    public static var test:String="hi";
}
```

...when I don't know Blah in advance?

Running Haxe 3.2.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
var cl = Type.resolveClass("Blah");
trace(Reflect.field(cl, "test"));
```

Static fields need to be accessed through a `Class<T>` type, so `createEmptyInstance()` doesn't work here. You need to pass an instance to `Reflect.field()` if you want to retrieve the value of an instance field.

You also need to make sure that `Blah` is actually compiled and available at runtime. If it is only referenced via reflection, this won't be the case - it needs to be imported somewhere. If you have DCE enabled, the class additionally needs `@:keep` metadata.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realized that `Reflect.field` could take a class too, not only an instance.  Thanks!